# UICollectionViewCell Deselect Pre-Selected Cell on First Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am modally presenting a `viewcontroller` that hosts a `viewcollection` with "pre-selected" cells formatted to a different background color based on data passed on segue.

When I tap on one of these "pre-selected" cells, it takes two taps to trigger the `didDeselectItemAt` delegate method. I understand why this is happening while debugging, where the cell although of different color is not necessarily recognized in a selected state. **Is there any way to trigger `didDeselectItemAt` first for the "pre-selected" cells?**

I've tried, within the delegate method `cellForItemAt`, to incorporate, as part of a conditional statement that changes the cell background color, setting `cell.isSelected = true`. Similarly within the same delegate method, I've also tried invoking a function that would invoke the delegate method `didSelectItemAt` with indexPaths of these "pre-selected" cells. Both produced the same result.

Below is (abbreviated) relevant code snippets:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ExampleCollectionViewCell

    if preselectedDataPoints { cell.backgroundColor = blue }
    else { cell.backgroundColor = white }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = blue
    preselectedDataPoints.append(newDataPoint)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor = white
    preselectedDataPoints.remove(at: existingDataPoint)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programatically call `collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)` in didSelectItem if cell is preselected.

Refrer code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if preselectedDataPoints { 
       collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true) 
    }else{
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
       cell?.backgroundColor = blue
       preselectedDataPoints.append(newDataPoint)
    }  

}
```

**or**

Directly call what ever code you need to execute in deSelect method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if preselectedDataPoints { 
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
       cell?.backgroundColor = white
       preselectedDataPoints.remove(at: existingDataPoint)
    }else{
       let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
       cell?.backgroundColor = blue
       preselectedDataPoints.append(newDataPoint)
    }  

}
```

Comment: I received an error with the 1st suggestion in invoking deSelect within didSelectItem, perhaps some conflict with the parameter involved? 2nd suggestion called the didDeselect delegate method on 2nd tap so I still needed to maintain the code in there. What solved it for me is building off the 2nd suggestion in combining all conditional statements and having them in both delegate methods. This way, regardless of method triggered, the same data and logic is executed and volleyed back and forth.